# How can I reduce space between section heading and numbering without any package?

Tags: sectioning, titles, titlesec

I want to create a book style by modifying one of the standard book styles like `book.cls`, `extbook.cls`, `memoir.cls` .

> How can I reduce space between section heading and numbering internally without any package?

I have found many related question in this website that almost all of answers referred to `titlesec` or similar package.

Comment: This depends on how the `\section` commands have been defined, i.e., it depends on the document class that you use as well as any packages that modify these commands. First decide on the class.

Comment: Why aren't you wanting to use any packages?  It wouldn't be hard to start with a standard book style, `\RequirePackage{titlesec}`, and then go from there.  If you're not wanting to require the presence of titlesec, then why can you expect any portion of the standard tex distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly do not modify any of the `.cls` files themselves.

For the `memoir` class:

```
% secnumprob2.tex  SE 516274 reduce space after section number
\documentclass{memoir}

\newlength{\mylength} % a length for convenience

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{Section}
\setlength{\mylength}{0.5em}
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{\mylength}} 
\section{Another}
\end{document}
```

See section 6.6 *Lower level headings* in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`). The macro `\setsecnumformat` defines the setting of the section numbers. It's default is `\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}`. In the MWE above I changed the `\quad` to `\hspace{\mylength}` to give `\mylength` space between the section number and the title for the second and succeeding sections.